# Importing OBJ and separating by Loose parts

Tags: rendering, animation, mesh, import, obj

I am trying to import an assembly file from Onshape into Blender. I am exporting out of Onshape as OBJ. Here is a picture of the Onshape assembly:

[image]

It is an enclosure with some parts inside. My end goal is to create an exploded view of the enclosure. Here is what an exploded view in Onshape looks like:

[image]

As we can see, there are 5 unique parts. After bringing it in to Blender, I get the following:

[image]

The enclosure appears, but instead of just a few meshes appearing, there are hundreds. This means that I can do things like this:

[image]

I can pull faces off of the objects which should be a part. Instead of being unique solid parts, I can pull surfaces off of parts. That base piece should be one part, but I can pull an edge outer face off of it.

I go into edit mode, and click *Separate by Loose Parts*. I then exit edit mode and go into viewport shading, and under color, I select "random".

My expectation is that there should just be 5 colors on the assembly, since there are 5 unique parts which I just separated the assembly into. Instead, I get this:

[image]

And I can still move surfaces off of parts:

[image]

Now I could go into the scene collection and join all the meshes and rebuild each of the parts into one solid piece. This would take a long time.

Is there anyway to get this assembly into blender, and then sperate back into just the 5 parts that I want. Essentially, I just want to interact with the 5 parts and apply materials to them in Blender.

For reference, I am following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KFb4r8UVO0A&ab_channel=DerekElliott

Comment: Blender can only work with what's been imported in the Obj file. It sounds as if "Onshape" (whatever that is) is exporting your object in lots of different parts rather than just 5 so there's not much you can do in Blender apart from joining the parts back together manually.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, this is what I suspected. Onshape is a CAD software just like Solidworks or Fusion 360. I'll try to export the same thing with Solidworks and see if I get the same issue. Thanks again for the info on this.

Comment: You can try the "Merge By Distance" in Edit Mode before the separtion. If it merges too much things together, you should move the parts in the other software before exporting, then undo it. Or export it one by one, still faster. Or if you can set different materials int the CAD software you can separate by them.